# Ruby Case Comparison

Tags: ruby, sqlite, case-insensitive

Rookie here

I am trying to get ignore cases when comparing two twitter handles. One is in the users database which is being retrieved into the valid_handles_results array. I want to compare the Twitter handle from a separate database where twitter handles are stored at record[1] column.

I am getting the following error :

> undefined method `casecmp' for ["theFancyPies"]:Array

Any suggestions?

```
all_orders_in_a_order_results.each do |record|

# check whether the tweet is unique or not, if yes then check whether the user has an account or not
# # the following query checks that the new entry being put in the all_orders_ordered database is unique or not
count_orders = @all_ordersDB.get_first_value('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM all_orders_ordered WHERE tweet_id = ? AND time_of_tweet = ? ' ,[record[5], record[4]])
unique_ordered = (count_orders ==0 )


# Query for selecting twitter_handles for all the users that are registered
valid_handles = %{SELECT twitter_handle FROM users}
valid_handles_results = @userDb.execute valid_handles

user_status = 0

valid_handles_results.each do |valid_handle|

      if valid_handle.casecmp(record[1]) ==0 

          user_status = 1
      else
          user_status = 0

      end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing your `valid_handles` query the result of this is an array of arrays. Even though you're only selecting a single column (`SELECT twitter_handle FROM...`) the entries in the `valid_handles_results` array are arrays containing a single element.

So to fix the error replace `valid_handle.casecmp(record[1])` with `valid_handle[0].casecmp(record[1])`

While this may seem a little confusing at first, the reason behind this is that it means `@userDb.execute` can return a consistent structure regardless of the number of columns being selected in the query.

To help with debugging similar errors in the future, it's really helpful to get to understand "undefined method" errors. `` undefined method `casecmp' for ["theFancyPies"]:Array `` is telling you that you tried to call `casecmp` but the object you tried to call it on does not have a method with that name. The `:Array` is telling you the class of the object you called the method on. So in this instance you had an `Array` when you were expecting a `String`.